# ModuleNotFound:No module named'imutils'

Tags: drivers, python3, pycharm

i have already installed imutils using pip (which is upgraded to the last version), and  imutils is supposed to be on PyCharm ExternalModules directly after installation , but the thing is this , when i came to run my program that uses imutils modules, it printed the Modulerror that imutils is not found, what to do?

Comment: Can you please share more details of the error.

Comment: I got this: /home/manel/.virtualenvs/tutorialpoint/bin/python /home/manel/Documents/opencv-tutorial/opencv_tutorial_01.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/manel/Documents/opencv-tutorial/opencv_tutorial_01.py", line 5, in <module>
    import imutils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imutils'